# convert QImage to QVideoFrame in PySide6

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pyside6

I'm having trouble porting my application to PySide6 from PySide2.

I'm reading my camera with the gphoto2 library and created a PIL Image from it in preview mode. It's like a live viewfinder, showing the user what the camera currently sees.

Previously, I implemented a custom FrameProvider and used it as the source for my VideoOutput QML type. A QVideoFrame could be easily converted from a QImage:

```
frame = QVideoFrame(QImage(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "./res/initialization.jpg"))) # PySide2 conversion
```

As both VideoOutput and QVideoFrame have changed in PySide6, I've implemented a custom VideoSink class, that exposes the videoSink of the VideoOutput I want to use:

```
VideoSink {
    id: videoSink
    videoSink: main.videoSink
}

VideoOutput {
    id: main
    anchors.fill: parent
    fillMode: VideoOutput.Stretch
}
```

This is the python code of my VideoSink class:

```
class VideoSink(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideoSink, self).__init__(parent)
        self.sink = None

    @Signal
    def sinkChanged(self):
        pass

    def get_sink(self):
        return self.sink

    def set_sink(self, sink):
        self.sink = sink
        frame = QVideoFrame(QImage(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "./res/initialization.jpg"))) # not working in PySide6 :-(
        self.sink.setVideoFrame(frame)
        self.sinkChanged.emit()

    videoSink = Property(
        QObject, get_sink, set_sink, notify=sinkChanged
    )
```

However, the only thing that is missing is the conversion to a QVideoFrame. Unfortunately I cannot use the constructor method anymore in PySide6. Therefore I'm looking for a different way to create a QVideoFrame from a QImage, or maybe even a different way to show a stream of images in PySide6 altogether

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert QImage to QVideoFrame so I would set it as frame for VideoSink Qt6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71407367/how-to-convert-qimage-to-qvideoframe-so-i-would-set-it-as-frame-for-videosink-qt)